# Strange Overleaf Glitch- inserting blank space on objects such as enumerate

Tags: spacing, overleaf

As the screenshot shows, when I hit enter to create an environment such as enumerate, overleaf inserts a block of empty space which jumps to the next line when I press tab. What is the cause of this?

[image]

Comment: Have you contacted the Overleaf helpdesk? I hear their support staff are really good.

Comment: it isn't clear what you are asking about, which space in the image is wrong?

Comment: After the \item there's a weird glitch where if I press tab it breaks a line as if I'd pressed enter